# × TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) 
App C:/Users/T.N shukla/whatsapp/src/App.js:10


7 | import {useStateValue} from './StateProvider';
   8 | 
   9 | function App() {
> 10 |   const [ user ,setdispatch]=useStateValue(); 
  11 |  
  12 |   return (
  13 |     <div className="App">
```

Comment: What are you expecting to get out of this post? There is no context, no question, really nothing to work with. `useStateValue` most likely contains the problem.

Comment: Your question doesnt have enough explanation to your problem, try to console log the user looks like its not an array, set the initial state value to an empty array.

Comment: Hey Ram. You will have to explain a bit more about the problem you are facing. People can help you only if you can explain the question enough. Also, it seems like a problem with your own configuration (It's a wild guess). Before posting here I would suggest google it.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when you try to iterate (for example, using a for loop) on an object which is not iterable (for example, you tried to iterate on an object not an array of objects).

for example, say I had an object like this:

```
let myObject = {
name: 'sam',
data: 'whatever'
}
```

If I try to do `for (let item of myObject) {some code}`
I would get the error you are getting.

including some more information about the code or uploading it to GitHub would help us fix your problem faster!

good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap app.js component in the StateProvider component. Pass the initial state and reducer function as props and access it in the state Provider component.

Hope you will find it useful :)